# Only one CPU is being used

Tags: 12.04, asus, cpu

I am running ubuntu 12.04.5, have an Asus N53sv and I am have the same problem as the post below, but becuase my bios is different I can not apply the same fix.

[How to fix that only one out of four cores of my CPU is detected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/247028/how-to-fix-that-only-one-out-of-four-cores-of-my-cpu-is-detected)

I have added the same `nolapic` to grub to allow me to start  and shut down the computer properly.

In my BIOS there was no `Installer OS select`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

### SYSTEM INFORMATION

`lscpu` outputs:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                1
On-line CPU(s) list:   0
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
BogoMIPS:              3991.09
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0
```

and `lshw -class cpu`

```
  *-cpu                   
   description: CPU
   product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
   vendor: Intel Corp.
   physical id: 4
   bus info: cpu@0
   version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   slot: CPU 1
   size: 2001MHz
   capacity: 4GHz
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 100MHz
   capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid cpufreq
   configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=1 threads=2
```

and `dmidecode` gives

```
BIOS Information
Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
Version: N53SV.209
Release Date: 02/10/2011
Address: 0xF0000
Runtime Size: 64 kB
ROM Size: 2560 kB
Characteristics:
    PCI is supported
    BIOS is upgradeable
    BIOS shadowing is allowed
    Boot from CD is supported
    Selectable boot is supported
    EDD is supported
    5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
    Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
    8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
    Serial services are supported (int 14h)
    Printer services are supported (int 17h)
    ACPI is supported
    USB legacy is supported
    Smart battery is supported
    BIOS boot specification is supported
    Targeted content distribution is supported
BIOS Revision: 4.6

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
Manufacturer: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
Product Name: N53SV
Version: 1.0       
Serial Number: BSN12345678901234567
Asset Tag: ATN12345678901234567
Features:
    Board is a hosting board
    Board is replaceable
Location In Chassis: MIDDLE              
Chassis Handle: 0x0003
Type: Motherboard
Contained Object Handles: 0
```

[image: Bios pic 1]

[image: Bios pic 2]

[image: Bios pic 3]

[image: Bios pic 4]

[image: Bios pic 5]

[image: Bios pic 6]

[image: Bios pic 7]

Comment: Does bios show all cores?

Comment: Sorry I am not the best with computers. How would I check that?

Comment: Go into your bios settings and see there. It depends on hardware how to enter there.

Comment: I just checked and the information provided there is very limited. No mention the cores.  I took pictures of my BIOS but they are too big to post here. Is there a good way of sharing the pictures?

Comment: Upload them somewhere and post a link.

Comment: Pictures were re-sized and added above

Comment: It seems that the kernel does not support this cpu well. Why not install Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The distribution I am running says not to upgrade to Ubuntu 14 or the programs will not work correctly.  Should this be moved to a discussion?

Comment: You are Bios number 209. You should upgrade to BIOS number 215 see: http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/271/0/6/Gjsm3Kp4pjz9iJM1/30/

Comment: @BaisJohn And what is the distribution that tells not to upgrade?

Comment: I am using CAELinux http://caelinux.com/CMS/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=2&id=7809&Itemid=300025

Comment: @Doug Smythies,  I will attempt a BIOS upgrade. fingers crossed.

Comment: I updated the BIOS to 215. But I still need nolapic to start and shut down the computer properly

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26502), particularly comments 28-30. I looked at the manual for your computer model, and you have that setting on your security tab, but myself I would try the defaults.

Comment: @DougSmythies I have added more pics of my BIOS. In my security tab there is no `new interface card` setting. I tried the `restore defults` on the `save & exit` tab, but there was no change.