# How to enable all the cores available in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cpu, multi-core, intel-cpu, lshw

When I executed the command:

```
sudo lshw | grep core
```

It's showing following output:

```
cores:2 cores_enabled:1 threads:2
```

How can I enable both cores? (Ubuntu 18.04).

Edit:

No options visible in BIOS

output for: cat /etc/default/grub is

[image: grub result]

output for sudo lscpu -a --extended is

[image: lscpu result]

Comment: This probably due to a BIOS setting. Check in your BIOS if something like `multi-core support` is disabled and enable it. Or maybe [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/247028/968501). Or if not, please [edit] your question and add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

Comment: Or, it could be a bug/limitation of `lshw`. Try `sudo lscpu -a --extended`

Comment: When I compared performance with same configuration device. Machine seems to be slower almost half. Is that an issue due to cores_enabled:1

Comment: Does `sudo lscpu -a --extended` show threads or CPU cores?